# Generate MS Graph Outlook Task Access Token from Sharepoint

Tags: sharepoint, microsoft-graph-api, sharepointframework

I want to read all the Outlook Task assigned to the logged in user from with an Office365 web part (SPFX), But I do not want the user to sign in again or do any such operation, Ideally what I want is to use SharePoint context to be used to authenticate the user.

I came across the `GraphHttpClient` which uses `/_api/SP.OAuth.Token/Acquire` to acquire an access token which can be used with Microsoft Graph but, by default, this method only issue `Group.ReadWrite.All` and `Reports.Read.All` permission.

I need to grant it `Tasks.Read` permission.

I was wondering if there is any way to pass the Scope into the method to get an updated token?

I have already tried passing Scope as a query string to URL and as a header, both yielded me no result. Any suggestions on how to tackle this issue will be helpful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [`GraphHttpClient`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/spfx/overview-graphhttpclient) has been deprecated, you want to use the new [`MSGraphClient`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/spfx/use-msgraph) instead.

By default, `MSGraphClient` doesn't have any permission scopes applied other than `User.Read`. It does, however, support requesting additional permission scopes from the tenant administrator. The overview for how this works can be found at [Connect to Azure AD-secured APIs in SharePoint Framework solutions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/spfx/use-aadhttpclient).

Comment: I checked the same documentation yesterday, but "AadHttpClient and MSGraphClient client objects are currently in preview and are subject to change. Do not use them in a production environment. Also note that the webApiPermissionRequests properties in package-solution.json are not supported in production tenants".

Comment: Hey I am still confused, should I use "MSGraphClient" in production environment? @marc-lafleur

Comment: It isn't recommended, no. But keep in mind, `GraphHttpClient` was _also_ in Preview and subject to the same non-production recommendation. `MSGraphClient` is also the only client that supports the scenario you described. In the end, you need to use your own discretion when deciding to pull a dependency on any preview bits.

Comment: Ya I was thinking the same. Thanks mate.